# React axios get return empty array

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

As I mentioned, console.log print only empty array. I think the problem will related with async problem.

This is the error what I got.
[image]

So, I make delay in axios, return with isLoading but still not working.

Has any solution? Thanks for help!

Test.js(parent component, every state in here) -> MainTest.js -> Question.js

Test.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Tutorial from "../Tutorial";
import MainTest from "../MainTest";
import axios from "axios";

const Test = () => {
    
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [questionNum, setQuestionNum] = useState(0);
    const [questionList, setQuestionList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/get/question").then((response) => {
            setQuestionList(response.data);
        })
    }, []);

    const questionHandler = () => {
        setQuestionNum(questionNum + 1);
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
        <div>
           
            <MainTest
                questionList={questionList}
                questionNum={questionNum}
                questionHandler={questionHandler}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

MainTest.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import ProgBar from './ProgBar'
import Question from './Question'
import SelectSec from './SelectSec'

function MainTest({questionList, questionNum, questionHandler}) {
    return (
        <TestWrap>
            <ProgBar />
            <Question questionList={questionList[questionNum]}/>
            <SelectSec questionList={questionList[questionNum]} questionHandler={questionHandler}/>
        </TestWrap>
    )
}

export default MainTest

const TestWrap = styled.div`
width: 100vh;
height: 100vh;
background-image: url("./images/background/background.png");
`;
```

Question.js

```
import React from "react";
import Styled from "styled-components";

function Question({questionList}) {
    console.log(questionList)
    return (
        <QuestionWrap>
            <i className="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <h3>
            {questionList.question.split('</br>').map(line => {
                        return(<>{line}<br/></>)
                    })}
            </h3>
        </QuestionWrap>
    );
}

export default Question;

const QuestionWrap = Styled.div `
width: 100%;
height: 55%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
 i{
     color: #b56467;
     font-size: 2rem;
     margin-bottom: 2rem;
 }
 h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "UhBeeBEOJJI";
    color: #3a1a00;
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    line-height: 3.4rem;
 }
`;
```

Comment: this is because your console.log is trig before the questionList is filled.
try to wrap this console log in a useffect wit questionList in useEffect dependency

Comment: @antoineso Hi. Thanks for quick reply. I did what you saying but still got error.... haha

Comment: I have updated my answer I thought that questionList was an Array in Question component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Question component you need to had a condition in the return like:

```
function Question({questionList}) {
    console.log(questionList)
    return (
        <QuestionWrap>
            <i className="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <h3>
            {questionList & questionList.question && questionList.question.split('</br>').map(line => {
                        return(<>{line}<br/></>)
                    })}
            </h3>
        </QuestionWrap>
    );
}

export default Question;
```